# Can I change the way matplotlib renders the r label for the values?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently working on building a polar graph with matplotlib, I manage to get the following result,

[image]

I know I can show only half that the r labels will look better but I was trying to get something like this,

[image]

The important part it the right part of the graph, the left it's just a mirror of it, but it's interesting to show (for this specific project), I was just trying to get the r labels out of the graph so everything looks a bit more readable, I know I can rotate them but is there a way to do more? Like change the position like it's on the second image?